# If/ elseif giving wrong output

Tags: powershell

I am having issues with a script returning the correct output:

```
$maximiser = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\System32\maximiser.tsp | select Name
$ID6 = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID6 
$ID5 = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID5
$ID4 = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID4
$ID3 = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID3
$ID2 = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID2
$ID1 = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID1
$ID = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | select ProviderID
$nomax = "Maximiser no installed"
$noid = "ProviderID not configured"
Write-Host 'This Computer is called' $env:COMPUTERNAME 
if ($maximiser = $maximiser) {
write-host "Maxmiser installed"}
Else {write-host "$nomax"}
if ($ID6 = $ID6 ) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Elseif ($ID5 = $ID5) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Elseif ($ID4 = $ID4) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Elseif ($ID3 = $ID3) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Elseif ($ID2 = $ID2) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Elseif ($ID1 = $ID1) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Elseif ($ID = $ID) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"} 
Else {Write-Host "Provider ID not Configured"}
```

For some reason - i keep on getting back "Maximiser Installed" and "Provider ID Configured" even though they are not. Am i missing something major in this?

**Edit**
If have found to get my answer (because we have multiple providerID's) 
using :

```
if ($ID -like (Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' | Select-Object -expandproperty ProviderID )) {
write-host "Provider ID Configured"}
Else {Write-Host "Provider ID not Configured"}
```

This seems to work!

Comment: 1) Use `-eq` and not `=` for equality comparison and 2) note that comparing a value to itself will always yield `$true` so all subsequent clauses don't really make sense in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ...

```
If ($ID.ProviderID -ne $null) {

    # Action if  ProviderID in 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\' doesnt has a value.

}
```

... in its current state should work.

Also you do not need to fetch the same data 7 times into different variables ... it will be there.

```
$ID = Get-Itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Telephony\Providers\'
```

... will result in ...

```
$ID.ProviderID
$ID.ProviderID1
..
$ID.ProviderID6
```

... having the data you need for comparison.

Comment: Thank you for this - your way is a lot more elegant than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Correct notation in Powershell is "-eq" rather than "=".

With "=" you are assigning a value, not comparing it.

Also, "$something -eq $something" will never evaluate to $false. It will always be equal to itself, even if the variable has no value at all.

Comment: Thanks for this - how would i go about correcting the script so that it gives the correct information ?